# searchView setQuery does not work

Tags: android

I am using the Search interface in andriod, and folowing the android guide I have set up the the interface.

I create a SearchableActivity which will handle both the user input the search result.

Now I meet a problem in that when user input something in the `SearchView` and hit the search key, the Search requset will be submited, then I will receive the query string and do the search, but at this moment, the text in the `SearchView` was changed to the default `SearchHit` value while I want it to be the query string.

So I tried to use the `searchView.setQuery(query, false);`, but it does not work, what's the problem?

The core Activity codes:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity_layout);

    Log.d("map", "create");
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("map", "handleIntent");
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //try search
        Log.d("map", "search and set query:" + query);
        searchView.setQuery(query, false); // reset the value in of the SearchView
    }
}
```

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MapActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: did u solve the problem. even i struck at the same point.

Answer (score 19):

I suggest you to delay the setting until the next event loop (add it to the message queue), so the code may looks like this:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        final String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        searchView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Important! Make sure searchView has been initialized
                // and referenced to the correct (current) SearchView.
                // Config changes (e.g. screen rotation) may make the
                // variable value null.
                searchView.setQuery(query, false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks it has potential, but I still can't set it to a `SearchView` initialized inside a `Menu`.

Comment: @JorgeAmVF have you set the `searchView` field to the menu created, right after inflating it? Probably in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Basically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555633/how-to-setquery-from-voice-search) is what I'm using, @fikr4n, and now I added your piece to the `handleIntent()` which is triggered `onNewIntent`. As the `SearchView` is initialized inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, the `searchView` can be caught outside with the help of a declaration, but when the text change is triggered the app fails. In my case, I'm able to set a filter to my adapter when I write and I'm able to initialize a `TextView` and pass the transcribed voice search to it, but not able to update the query from voice.

Answer (score 14):

This doesn't work

```
    mSearchView.setQuery(mKeyword, true);
    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(mMenuSearch);
```

This does

```
    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(mMenuSearch);
    mSearchView.setQuery(mKeyword, true);
```

It seems it only remembers it after you expanded the action view.
I'm using MenuItemCompat just for backwards compatibility

Comment: mSearchView.onActionViewExpanded(); mSearchView.setQuery("", true); worked for me

Answer (score 4):

need to put code in post handler with MenuItemCompat

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_my_team, menu);
    // search manager integration for search widget
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    //    MenuItem helpTutorialMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_help);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search by");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(queryText)) {
        mSearchView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);
                mSearchView.setQuery(queryText, false);
            }
        });
    }
    mSearchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Should pull the `MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);` out of run and add before post. This had always been working for me, but noticed it was not on a Nougat device I was testing.

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when the intent with Action `Intent.ACTION_SEARCH` is received, the following method will be called:

```
handleIntent();

onCreateOptionsMenu();
```

And the `handleIntent` will run before the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

At the same time, people used to setup the `searchView` at the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Which means that the option menu will be re-inflated, and the `searchView` will be re-build, then all the settings in the `handleIntent` will not work.

I think this is the reason.

Please feel free to fix me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it wasn't working because the fragment I was in was no longer attached to the window. Moving it to above where I swapped in the new search results fragment fixed it.